# Concatenation of strings

Tags: divisibility, regular-expressions

We have two strings A and B.
We have to find if for some n,m A concatenated n times equals B concatenated m times or not.
I have made an interesting observation but am unable to prove it.It appears that this can happen if and only if AB=BA

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**. Show that $A^n = B^m$ implies that $A = C^i$ and $B = C^j$.

Comment: how so? cant think of a way, though it sounds intuitive

Comment: $A^x$ and $B^y$, for any $x,y$ share a prefix. Consider $x, y$ such that $|A^x| < |B^y| < |A^{x+1}|$. Write $B^y$ as $A^x\beta$ where $\beta$ is a suffix of $B$. Notice that $\beta$ is also a prefix of $A$. Show that $|\beta|$ can take any value divisible by $\gcd(|A|, |B|)$. Now, if $C$ is a suffix of $B$ and a prefix of $A$, and you find a $|\beta| = 2|C|$, then $\beta = C^2$. Rinse and repeat. Even though it's a simple statement, I can't think of a simpler proof...

Answer (score 0):

Let $A,B\in\Sigma^*$ be nonempty(!) words over the alphabet $\Sigma$.

Assume $AB=BA$. Let $n=|B|, m=|A|$. Then by looking at the first $nm$ symbols of $A^nB^m=B^mA^n$ we find $A^n=B^m$.

Assume $A^n=B^m$ with $n,m\ge 1$.
If $n=1$ then $AB=B^{m+1}=BA$ and we are done.
If $m=1$ then $AB=A^{n+1}=BA$ and we are done.
So we may assume $n,m\ge 2$.
Then the words $B^{m+1}=BA^n$ and $A^{n+1}=AB^m$ have $A^n=B^m$ as common prefix of length at least $m|B|=n|A|\ge 2\max\{|A|,|B|\}\ge |A|+|B|$. Therefore we have equality for the prefix of length $|A|+|B|$, i.e. $AB=BA$.